# How to transition this MySql subquery to a join query?

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I've created a mysql query which includes a subquery which I'd like to convert to a join query.

The reason I'm using a subquery is I need to have the where condition at the end applied to **result** of the that subquery.  Here's the query:

```
 select date, system_name, device_name, valid_read_rate from 
(SELECT  left(from_unixtime(c.capture_time/1000),10) as date,  a.name as 'system_name', b.name as 'device_name', c.read_count, c.valid_object_count, 
if(valid_object_count = 0,'00.00%',concat(format(read_count/valid_object_count*100,2),'%')) as valid_read_rate, read_count/valid_object_count*100 as valid_read_rate_unformatted
FROM  sick_il_services.system_config a
join sick_il_services.system_device b
on a.id = b.system_id
join sick_il_aap.daily_device_read_rate c
on b.id = c.device_id
where 1=1
group by c.capture_time,a.name, b.name
order by c.capture_time, a.name, b.name) as sub
where sub.valid_read_rate_unformatted < 100
```

I'm just having trouble getting untracked on this. Any advice welcome.

Comment: This is presenting as an xy problem. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: The query you posted doesn't parse. It has imbalanced parentheses. Are you sure you posted the whole query?

Comment: I've reposted it - just ran it - can you try again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as whatever format you are using allows you to filter columns later, the subquery wasn't particularly doing much from what I can tell. This *should* cover what you are doing, however, without a `CREATE TABLE` syntax, I cannot verify the answer.

```
SELECT left(from_unixtime(c.capture_time / 1000), 10)                    as date,
       a.name                                                            as 'system_name',
       b.name                                                            as 'device_name',
       c.read_count,
       c.valid_object_count,
       if(valid_object_count = 0, '00.00%',
       concat(format(read_count / valid_object_count * 100, 2), '%')) as valid_read_rate
FROM sick_il_services.system_config a
         join sick_il_services.system_device b on a.id = b.system_id
         join sick_il_aap.daily_device_read_rate c on b.id = c.device_id
where (c.read_count / c.valid_object_count * 100) < 100
group by c.capture_time, a.name, b.name
order by c.capture_time, a.name, b.name
```

---

## Updated from the comments

In your comment, you mention that you might be looking for a summed average from your grouping. In that case, you might be looking to do something along the following

```
SELECT left(from_unixtime(c.capture_time / 1000), 10)                    as date,
       a.name                                                            as 'system_name',
       b.name                                                            as 'device_name',
       c.read_count,
       c.valid_object_count,
       if(valid_object_count = 0, '00.00%',
       concat(format(read_count / valid_object_count * 100, 2), '%')) as valid_read_rate
FROM sick_il_services.system_config a
         join sick_il_services.system_device b on a.id = b.system_id
         join sick_il_aap.daily_device_read_rate c on b.id = c.device_id
group by c.capture_time, a.name, b.name
having (sum(read_count)/sum(valid_object_count)) < 1
order by c.capture_time, a.name, b.name
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback. I thought that the results were different when I calculated the read-rate inside the grouping, which is why I created the subquery. Could it be due to the fact that the average is calculated before the grouping? But I'll check in anyway, maybe I just didn't get it right.

Comment: If that is the case, are you expecting your results from `read_count` and `valid_object_count` to be summed when grouped? If that is the case, then you can do the where statement to a `HAVING`, moving it to the bottom, and adding `(sum(read_count)/sum(valid_object_count)) < 1`, which might be closer to what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, that sounds good. Could I ask you a huge favor and post what you're saying?  I will also try on my own.

Comment: I've updated my answer, let me know if that helps

Comment: I had to remove the "order by", but then it works and it looks like it's in order. Thank you - I have never understood until now what the having clause meant!

Comment: My bad with the orderby: if you put it back in place, just put it after the having and it should work. I will update my answer accordingly

Comment: Yes, works like a dream. Perfect, thanks again.